# Vim and gVim file type detection

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

OS: CentOS 5.7

I am trying to get both gVim/Vim have syntax highlight for a new file type. So far I did:

- Create syntax file at `~/.vim/ftdetect/foo.vim`.
- Using Vim can automatically detect the new file type and enable syntax highlighting. `$ vim myfile.foo`
- But gVim doesn't have syntax highlighting.

I tried to add this line in `~/.gvimrc`:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.foo set filetype=foo
```

But it looks like gVim didn't load `~/.vim/ftdetect/foo.vim` at all. How should I configure gVim?

- Move the `foo.vim` to `~/.vim/syntax/` doesn't work for both Vim/gVim. They can't auto detect `~/.vim/syntax` folder.
- Below are the scriptnames list (+ sign to indicate extra files loaded by gVim), gVim does load foo.vim, but not sure how to figure out what's overwrite the foo.vim settings. Since using `:set syntax=foo` in gVim won't work either.
- `:au BufRead,BufNewFile *.foo` shows no detection rule for both vim/gVim. So the Vim just magically works...
- This is the [syntax rule](http://www1.verigy.com/cntrprod/groups/public/documents/file/wcmd_001419.txt). Is the version checking in the rule file causing gVim can't recognize the *.foo file?

[vim:scriptnames]

```
  1: /etc/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim70/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim70/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim70/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim70/filetype.vim
  6: /home/myusername/.vim/ftdetect/foo.vim
  7: /home/myusername/.vimrc
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim70/plugin/getscript.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim70/plugin/gzip.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim70/plugin/matchparen.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim70/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim70/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim70/plugin/spellfile.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim70/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim70/plugin/tohtml.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim70/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim70/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim70/scripts.vim
```

[GVIM :scriptnames]

```
  1: /etc/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim70/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim70/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim70/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim70/filetype.vim
  6: /home/myusername/.vim/ftdetect/foo.vim
+  7: /usr/share/vim/vim70/menu.vim
+  8: /usr/share/vim/vim70/autoload/paste.vim
  9: /home/myusername/.vimrc
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim70/plugin/getscript.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim70/plugin/gzip.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim70/plugin/matchparen.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim70/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim70/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim70/plugin/spellfile.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim70/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim70/plugin/tohtml.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim70/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim70/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
+ 20: /home/myusername/.gvimrc
+ 21: /usr/share/vim/vim70/colors/torte.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim70/scripts.vim
```

Comment: Put it into `~/.vim/syntax/`

Comment: Please add your syntax file to question.

Comment: Works fine for me. What is your vim/gvim version? Have you tried it with clean .vimrc/.gvimrc? (don't know much difference, my .gvimrc made just a symlink to .vimrc)

Comment: vim/gvim version = 7.0. GVIM seems doesn't know "foo" filetype at all.

Comment: Wait, you still trying it in `~/.vim/ftdetect`? This directory is for autocommand (`au`) rules, not for syntax files themselves. Put into syntax, then launch gvim with .foo file and type `:echo b:current_syntax`. If it will complain about unknown variable, type `:setf foo` and then echo again.

Comment: That works! With `:au BufRead,BufNewFile *.foo`, vim/gvim can auto detect foo files with correct syntax highlighting! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What gets loaded should be identical for Vim and gVim (unless you do crazy stuff like manipulating the `'runtimepath'` in your `.gvimrc`); you can check with `:scriptnames` whether your *syntax detection* script got loaded (and then, also the actual `syntax/foo.vim` syntax script).

Also, `:au BufRead,BufNewFile *.foo` should list your detection rule.

Does (other) syntax highlighting work in gVim?! If it doesn't, you have a general problem there.